# Is this true for a continuously differentiable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Prove or find a counterexample: if $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable with $f(0)=0$  then there exist continuous functions $g_1,\dots,g_n:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with
$$f(x)=x_1g_1(x_1,\dots, x_n)+\dots+x_ng_n(x_1,\dots, x_n)$$

I don't know where to start. Should I use the implicit function theorem?
Please give me some hints.

Happy new year.

Comment: How is differentiation defined here? It seems that the usual definition does not work.

Comment: @KennyLau How does the usual definition not work? What is your usual definition of differentiable for functions $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$?

Comment: @Arthur The usual definition of differentiable is for function $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ and is $f'(a) := \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(a+h) - f(a)} h$. There is also a definition for **partial** differentiability for functions $\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$, and also a **gradient** for functions $\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$, but the gradient is a vector.

Comment: @KennyLau There is also a common definition of _differentiable at a point $p$_ for any function $\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^m$. Such a function $h$ is said to be differentiable at $p$ if there is a linear map $L:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^m$ such that $\lim_{v\to p}\left(\frac{f(v) - f(p) - L(v)}{|v-p|}\right) = 0$. In other words, $h$ has a linear approximation at the point $p$. In the case $\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$, this just means a well-defined tangent plane (and $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ is a special case where it means a well-defined tangent line).

Comment: @Arthur when $m=1$, it is essentially the **gradient**.

Comment: @KennyLau Yes, that is true. When $m = 1$, $L$ is just the gradient, seen as a linear map from $\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$ (a _row vector_ in linear algebra). Still, I don't see how the definition fails to work, as you seem to claim.

Comment: @Arthur I'm not sure I understand your definition via linear map. Take $n=m=1$ and $f=\sin$. Are you saying that there is a constant $c$ such that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)-cx}{|x-0|} = 0$?

Comment: @KennyLau Yes, and that constant is $1$, and we usually call it "the derivative of the sine function at $x = 0$. At any other point than $0$, there is a different constant $c$. I realize now that I messed up the norm signs slightly, and they should've been around the numerator as well. It should've been $\lim_{v\to p}\frac{\|f(v) - f(p) - L(v)\|}{\|v-p\|} = 0$

Comment: FYI: This is Exercise 2-35 from Spivak's "Calculus on Manifolds".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix $x\in{\mathbb R}^n$ and consider the auxiliary function $$\phi(t):=f(t\,x)\qquad(0\leq t\leq 1)\ .$$
The chain rule then gives
$$f(x)=\phi(1)-\phi(0)=\int_0^1\phi'(t)\>dt=\int_0^1\nabla f(t\,x)\cdot x\>dt=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\,g_i(x)$$
with
$$g_i(x):=\int_0^1 f_{.i}(t\, x)\>dt\qquad(1\leq i\leq n)\ .$$

Comment: And what exactly is the difference between our functions?

Comment: @KennyLau: They are not the same. E.g., if $n=3$ your $g_2$ amounts to $\int_0^1f_{.2}(x,ty,0)\>dt$, and mine to $\int_0^1 f_{.2}(tx,ty,tz)\>dt$. But the $g_i$ are not uniquely determined anyway. The problem with your solution is that the continuity of the $g_i$ is not obvious. Note that your $g_i$ are defined without reference to differentiability.

Answer (score 1):

For $1 \le i \le n$, for $x_i \ne 0$, define:
$$g_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n) := \frac {f(x_1, \cdots, x_{i-1}, x_i, 0, 0, \cdots, 0) - f(x_1, \cdots, x_{i-1}, 0, 0, 0, \cdots, 0)} {x_i}$$

When $x_i = 0$, let $g_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ be its limit.

Note that $\displaystyle g_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \frac {f(x_1, 0, \cdots, 0) - f(0, 0, \cdots, 0)} {x_1} = \frac {f(x_1, 0, \cdots, 0)} {x_1}$.

It is a trivial exercise to show that $f = \sum x_i g_i$.

The well-definedness of such functions (i.e. the fact that the limit exists) and the continuity of such functions follow from the definition of "continuously differentiable", which unfortunately you have not provided.

---

For example, when $n=2$, this construction amounts to:
$$f(x,y) = x \left( \frac {f(x,0)} x \right) + y \left( \frac {f(x,y) - f(x,0)} y \right)$$

When $n=3$, this construction amounts to:
$$f(x,y,z) = x \left( \frac {f(x,0,0)} x \right) + y \left( \frac {f(x,y,0) - f(x,0,0)} y \right) + z \left( \frac {f(x,y,z) - f(x,y,0)} z \right)$$